# Programatically connect and disconnect USB devices in virtual machine

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, zen

I'm developing automated testing for software which needs to eject and reconnect USB devices automatically at the BUS level, not simply software.

This makes a virtual environment optimum because the virtual hardware can be controlled to emulate such behavior. However, I cannot find a way to do this programmatically through VMWare, VirtualBox, or Zen.

Is this kind of functionality implementable? Thank you!

Comment: Windows or Linux? What programming languages do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Windows 7+ is the focus, all programming languages are fair game.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372314/programatically-connect-and-disconnect-usb-devices-in-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

using VSPhere API, it's soap based web service that can do the same thing as you using VSphere client.

there is a interface called: ReconfigVM_Task may be you can use, see ref at:
[Vsphere API Reference](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html?path=7_1_0_2_5_16_25#reconfigure)